# Service Fabric Cluster VMSS on **Standard** Load Balancer

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-load-balancer

I had started with a Service Fabric Cluster (SFC) that was using the **Basic** SKU Load Balancer (LB). The SFC has Primary, FrontEnd, and BackEnd node types. Then I needed to change the FrontEnd LB to the **Standard** SKU in order to use the additional capability provided. The only thing modified in the LB ARM template was to specify the different SKU. Now the VMSS using the Standard LB cannot connect to the SFC and all the nodes appear in the 'Down' state. In order to deploy the different LB SKU, I had to delete the affected VMSS and LB. The LB is internal, connecting only to subnets with the VNet.

```
"sku": {
    "name": "Standard"
}
```

Other than changing the SKU property, are there any other settings required to allow the VMSS nodes to notify and connect to the SFC?

Answer (score 0):

When using an internal Standard Load Balancer, outbound NAT is not available until outbound connectivity has been explicitly declared. You can define outbound connectivity using an outbound rule to create outbound connectivity for VMs behind an internal Standard Load Balancer with these steps:

Create a public Standard Load Balancer.
Create a backend pool and place the VMs into a backend pool of the public Load Balancer in addition to the internal Load Balancer.
Configure an outbound rule on the public Load Balancer to program outbound NAT for these VMs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-rules-overview#outbound-nat-for-internal-standard-load-balancer-scenarios
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/configure-load-balancer-outbound-cli